# Get class from a div in Click Event in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, class, click

I have a click function defined on the document and when clicked I want to know if the target contains a class 'dropdown' the function should return. So this is what works fine in Firefox:

```
$(document).click(function(e){  
    if (e.target.classList.contains('dropdown'))
        return;

    //Other work here;
});
```

But somehow IE shows `e.target` as `null`. After reading some where that IE does not have `target` for click events but `srcElement`, and to work in both browsers I need to change this to:

```
(event.target || event.srcElement).id //etc
```

But I need to get the class attribute, does some one know how to get the class of the `srcElement` in IE "WITHOUT USING JQUERY"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the JQuery API function hasClass?

You should be able to replace

```
if(e.target.classList.contains('dropdown'))
```

with

```
if($(this).hasClass('dropdown'))
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~Edit~~~~~~~~~~

For that matter, if I understand what you're doing, perhaps you should restructure your whole event handler (unless you're doing it for efficiency reasons sometimes people catch a larger exception then figure out what was clicked)

```
$('.dropdown').each(function () {
    //Do some action
});
```

Comment: Actually I know how it can be done using JQuery, I dont want to use JQuery that is why I asked this question.

Comment: You had better re-ask the question then in a more specific manner if none of the current answers apply. Likely nobody will click your question any more if they see there are 3 answers, 1 with up-votes.  May I ask why you do not wish to use JQuery for this?

Comment: I am asking if this is possible without using jQuery, and the reason is that i could do this with Firefoxm thats why I need to know what is the equivalent thing in IE.

Comment: You could always dig through the JQuery API, its open source and built on Javascript after all, and its not magic.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery to the rescue:

```
$(document).click(function(e){  
   if($(this).hasClass("dropdown"))
      return    
    //Other work here;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$target = $(e.target);

if($target.hasClass("dropdown"))
    return;
```